# Python: raw_input a list

Tags: python, list, input

I want to take 2 values from keyboard and make a list with them, with a single comand. I made it like this, but I hope there is a "nicer" way:

```
 l=[raw_input("Inserisci i cateti: "),raw_input("Inserisci i cateti: ")]
```

to explain myselfe bettere, here's how I would do it in R:

```
a<-scan(n=2)
```

Any Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: How do you want the input to be formatted?

Comment: Seems find to me.  I guess if you really wanted to you could define a function for your input prompt and run it in a list-comprehension instead but there's nothing wrong with this per se.

Comment: @PauloBu I just want a normal input. It asks you "insert the values" and you input them.

Comment: @Iguananaut Ok, I'll define a function.

Comment: Looks like you already can do what you want to do -- maybe this is better suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll post there next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do is to have the user enter a single line with some kind of separator (e.g. a space or a comma).

```
items = raw_input("Enter your data items separated by commas: ").split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: def scan(n):
   ...:     return [raw_input("Inserisci i cateti: ") for _ in xrange(n)]
   ...: 

In [2]: scan(2)
Inserisci i cateti: i
Inserisci i cateti: j
Out[2]: ['i', 'j']

In [3]: scan(3)
Inserisci i cateti: a
Inserisci i cateti: b
Inserisci i cateti: c
Out[3]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```